# WordPress User Verification (Plugin) Status at BuddyPress Pending Page

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I would like to know how I can show verification status at this page https://prnt.sc/t0v4y7
On normal user list its working https://prnt.sc/t0v6eb

I want to know if the user had verified the account before I approve it.

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-verification/
I already made a topic at their support but it looks like they won't help me.

```
    <?php

/*
* @Author       pickplugins
* Copyright:    2015 pickplugins
*/

if ( ! defined('ABSPATH')) exit;  // if direct access 


class uv_class_column_users{
    
    public function __construct(){

        add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', array( $this, 'manage_users_custom_column_function' ), 10, 3 );
        add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', array( $this, 'manage_users_columns_function' ) );
        
        /*That arrow i have added but its not working: add_filter( 'bp_members_signup_columns', array( $this, 'manage_users_columns_function' ) ); */   
        add_filter( 'bp_members_signup_columns', array( $this, 'manage_users_columns_function' ) );
    }
    
    public function manage_users_columns_function( $columns ) {
        
        $new_columns    = array();
        $count          = 0;
        
        foreach( $columns as $column_key => $column_title ){
            $count++;
            
            if( $count == 3 ) $new_columns[ 'uv' ] = __('Verification Status', 'user-verification');
            else $new_columns[ $column_key ] = $column_title;
        }


        
        return $new_columns;
    }
    
    public function manage_users_custom_column_function( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
        

        
        $this_user      = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    
        if( $column_name == 'uv' ) {

            ob_start();
            $user_activation_status = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_activation_status', true );
            $user_activation_status = empty( $user_activation_status ) ? 0 : $user_activation_status;
            $uv_status              = $user_activation_status == 1 ? __('Verified', 'user-verification') : __('Pending Verify', 'user-verification');
                            
            echo "<div class='uv_status'>$uv_status</div>";
            echo "<div class='row-actions'>";
            
            
            if( $user_activation_status == 0 ) {
                
                echo "<span class='uv_action uv_approve' user_id='$user_id' do='approve'>".__('Verify Now', 'user-verification')."</span>";
            }
            
            if( $user_activation_status == 1 ) {
                
                echo "<span class='uv_action uv_remove_approval' user_id='$user_id' do='remove_approval'>".__('Remove Verification', 'user-verification')."</span>";
            }
            
            
            echo "</div>";

            return ob_get_clean();
        }else{
            return $val;
        }
        

    }

} new uv_class_column_users();
```

Can someone help me to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-verification-at-pending-page-buddypress/

They have updated their plugin with my request.